# Remove considering Blank while filtering Columns in Excell in POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Hi I am using autoFilter for filtering all Columns in Excell,it's considering all the blank rows (rows beyond the total no of rows having data) while filtering. but, i want to avoid considering Blank rows while i am trying to filter any column.

I am using below code,
sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A8:L13"));

I am currently getting like this
[image: I am currently getting like this]

I need like this
[image: I need like this]

Comment: The `[ ] (Blanks)` option only disappears if there are not blank cells in the filter range. So `sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A8:L13"));` in your special case.

Comment: that no 42 is not constant that's dynamic. In this case it must be 13..but problem is it's considering all the blank rows (rows beyond the total no of rows  having data) while filtering.

Comment: Then don't use a constant, whenever you add a row, reset the auto filter using `Sheet.getLastRow()`.

Answer (score 1):

The AutoFilter `[ ] (Blanks)` option only disappears if there are not blank cells in the filter range. So we need setting the AutoFilter cell range only to the used range.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;

import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;

class AutoFilterTest {

 private static void setCellData(Sheet sheet) {

  Row row = sheet.createRow(0);
  Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
  cell.setCellValue("Name");
  cell = row.createCell(1);
  cell.setCellValue("Value1");
  cell = row.createCell(2);
  cell.setCellValue("Value2");
  cell = row.createCell(3);
  cell.setCellValue("City");

  Random rnd = new Random();

  for (int r = 1; r < 10 + rnd.nextInt(100); r++) {
   row = sheet.createRow(r);
   cell = row.createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue("Name " + ((r-1) % 4 + 1));
   cell = row.createCell(1);
   cell.setCellValue(r * rnd.nextDouble());
   cell = row.createCell(2);
   cell.setCellValue(r * rnd.nextDouble());
   cell = row.createCell(3);
   cell.setCellValue("City " + ((r-1) % 3 + 1));  
  }

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
   XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
   XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet();

   //create random rows of data
   setCellData(sheet);

   for (int c = 0; c < 4; c++) sheet.autoSizeColumn(c);

   int lastRow = sheet.getLastRowNum();
   sheet.setAutoFilter(new CellRangeAddress(0, lastRow, 0, 3));

   wb.write(new FileOutputStream("AutoFilterTest.xlsx"));
   wb.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```